# Randomly generating integers to be used on a graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

the function of this program is to randomly generate numbers ranging from 1-10 for the variables  right, left, up, down to be used on a 40 x40  graph. in order to have a list containing 2 numbers for the x and y variables, i have another random number generator that picks which will be chosen

```
import random
choice_x = random.randint(0, 1)
choice_y = random.randint(0, 1)
right = random.randint(10, 20)
left = random.randint(0, 10)
up = left = random.randint(0, 10)
down = left = random.randint(10, 20)
directions = [right, left, up, down]

if choice_x == 0:
  del directions[right]
elif choice_x == 1:
  del directions[left]

if choice_y == 0:
  del directions[up]
elif choice_y == 1:
 del directions[down]
 print (directions)
```

whenever i try to execute this code, i keep getting a message stating "IndexError: list assignment index out of range"

Comment: What are you trying to do with `del directions[right]`?

Comment: You're using the indices incorrectly. `up, down, left, right` are values, with values greater than `len(directions)`. For instance `down = randint(10, 20)` means that `down > len(directions)` since `len(directions)` is 4, and `down >= 10`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your error is within the if statements. You're not indexing the `directions` list - you're trying to index a variable (`right`, `left`, `up`, `down`), hence the error.

Try this:

```
if choice_x == 0: del directions[0]
elif choice_x == 1: del directions[1]

if choice_y == 0: del directions[2]
elif choice_y == 1: del directions[3]
```